# Bridge wifi to lan on the same subnet

Tags: networking, network-bridge

I've got a Ubuntu 16.04 laptop connected to my lan via a wired ethernet port, and I need to share resources on the lan with a wireless device. How do I set Ubuntu up as a wireless access point that uses my lan's existing dhcp server and keeps the subnets the same?

Notes:

- using the hotspot functionality creates a new subnet, so not quite what I want
- I've verified by wireless adapter has AP listed as a supported interface mode
- I've been unsuccessful getting hostapd to run using older configuration HowTo's, but it sounds like this may be the key

Thanks

Comment: Did you try the steps in here:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConnectionBridge

Comment: @Terrance - I tried the gui link, and it created a separate lan. I assumed the manual commands did likewise, but will try it out.

Answer (score 2):

The link provided by Terrance got me started on the right track. The GUI method mentioned in that link doesn't do what I want, but the manual configuration worked. Additionally, hostapd had to be configured to handle the wifi side of the network.

For posterity, these are the pertinent configuration values:

My `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
  bridge_ports enp2s0 wlp1s0
```

My `/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`:

```
ssid=Silly Salmon
wpa_passphrase=mypassword
hw_mode=g
interface=wlp1s0
bridge=br0
driver=nl80211
country_code=US
channel=6
wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
auth_algs=1
macaddr_acl=0
```

After rebooting, the wireless ap provides an extension of the wired lan, and the dhcp server and dns server on the wired side is used by all wireless devices.